# In what file are values received from edit.php?

Tags: model-view-controller, joomla, joomla2.5, custom-component

I'm creating a custom field called *provinces* where I have built a multi-select field. This field receives a JSON keyless object `[3,4,5]` from the database which I then apply to the input in `getInput()` in province.php. I have managed to this on the output, but I need to write any values selected back to the database.

Where can I get the values that are then passed back if the user selects other options (in the back-end form edit.php) in the multi-select?

In other words, where is the `$_POST` array received before either it is redirected back to the form ***(Save)*** or to the list page ***(Save & Close)***?

Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

In the model for your form view, look for the function `prepareTable`. This is a good place to prepare/sanitize the data prior to saving.

If you want to process the data further after it is saved, you can use the function `postSaveHook` in your form controller.

Or you can of course also do something during save in the tables `store` function.